# Multiple app on nginx with specific port

Tags: django, nginx, port, gunicorn

I'm tring to make many django/gunicorn app on one server. Each app listen on one specific port. My nginx conf is like :

```
upstream my_app_2318 {
       server unix:/tmp/gunicorn-2318.sock    fail_timeout=10s
}
       server {
           listen                *:2318;
           server_name           example.com;

           index  index.html index.htm index.php;

           access_log            /opt/2318/logs/nginx_access.log combined;
           error_log             /opt/2318/logs/nginx_error.log;

           location / {
               proxy_pass            http://my_app_2318;
               proxy_read_timeout    90;
               proxy_connect_timeout 90;
               proxy_redirect        off;
           }
}
```

This conf work for GET request (when i acces to `example.com:2318/my-url`), but any POST request (submit form) redirect me on 80 port (`example.com/my-new-url`).

What's wrong with my conf ?

Thanks

Comment: Because you wrote `proxy_redirect        off;`

Comment: When i put `proxy_redirect default;` i have same problem

Comment: Check what exactly is in `Location` header

Comment: Check your html code, more specifically the `action` attribute of your `form` tag.

Comment: @AlexeyTen how can i check that ?

Comment: @emepe my html code is right. I have an action method with relative path like `action="/sub/"`

Comment: access log, tcpdump, net sniffer, etc

Comment: @AlexeyTen in my access log, i can see a POST request like : `[10/Mar/2015:09:07:49] "POST /unregister/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5210 "http://example.com:8000" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux)"` followed by `"[10/Mar/2015:09:08:05]" "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7465 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux)"`. The problem is there, i haven't no host in my GET redirection

Comment: `POST /unregister/ HTTP/1.1" 200 ...` means server returned html (not 301 or 302 redirect). Probably there is JS or META in that html, that do wrong redirect

Comment: Sorry i make a bad copy/paste. That's POST log `[10/Mar/2015:09:07:49] "POST /unregister/ HTTP/1.1" 302 5210 "http://example.com:8000" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux)`

Comment: UP please @AlexeyTen

Comment: As I wrote earlier, check what's in Location header. You could log it as `$upstream_http_location`

Comment: Indeed, my location header is `http://example.com/` whitout port. How can i put the port ?

Answer (score 1):

I have solution. The problem was in the header location.

I had need to use proxy_redirect header like this.

```
upstream my_app_2318 {
   server unix:/tmp/gunicorn-2318.sock    fail_timeout=10s
}
   server {
       listen                *:2318;
       server_name           example.com;

       index  index.html index.htm index.php;

       access_log            /opt/2318/logs/nginx_access.log combined;
       error_log             /opt/2318/logs/nginx_error.log;

       location / {
           proxy_pass            http://my_app_2318;
           proxy_redirect        http://example.com/ http://example.com:2318/;
           proxy_read_timeout    90;
           proxy_connect_timeout 90;
       }
}
```